# Is it safer to send cookies in headers than the URL?

Tags: tls, http, cookies

I have a browser extension. I would like to use this browser extension to send the cookie from site A to site B. I’m doing this because I want to scrape site A from site B, but this is obviously a use case browsers specifically designed against so I’m not sure how to handle it.

[It doesn’t seem like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64091604/authentication-across-across-multiple-domains-cors-with-nextauth) I can use the normal cookie methods because of how my authentication is set up. I’m wondering: is it any riskier to do `GET foo.com/?cookie=bar` vs. `GET foo.com header(cookie=bar)`? I'm using HTTPS.

Comment: Have you tried putting an iframe containing site A in Site B?  That seems like the place to start.  Sending cookie values doesn't seem necessary at all.

Comment: @pcalkins could you elaborate more? At some point I have to do an HTTP request that contains the cookie, right?

Comment: no, just let site A do that as it normally would.  Really your best option is to look to see if Site A has an API, though.  Many sites do these days.

Comment: basically do a POST call instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting an auth cookie value in the URL is a bad practice because it can be retrieved in the following locations (whether or not your are using https):

- Referer Header
- Web Logs
- Shared Systems
- Browser History
- Browser Cache
- Shoulder Surfing

So there is more risk that a third party impersonate the user session.

You should consult the OWASP about this case : https://owasp.org/www-community/vulnerabilities/Information_exposure_through_query_strings_in_url

Answer (score 0):

If the cookie contains any sensitive information or session information, you will not want that information inside of the URL. Users may take screenshots of URLs, paste URLs, or inadvertently print a URL when they print pages. If the URL were to contain, say, a session ID, then an attacker could steal that session.

If you have to set the cookie based off user input, consider using POST instead of GET.